# How to get correct file modification date?

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to get the last modified file from a list of files on a Raspberry Pi Pico W. MicroPython documentation says returned tuple of `os.stat` is the same as in Python. The following are probably correct:

- `os.stat()[0]` file type, regular or directory.
- `os.stat()[6]` file size.

`os.stat()[7]`, `os.stat()[8]` and `os.stat()[9]` are the same (modification time). For that value to be correct, the time has to be set. Time returned is correct:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.localtime()
```

But `os.stat()[7]` is not changing and incorrect. How can I get the file's correct last modification date?

Comment: Was the time set when the file was created? What kind of value do you get for `os.stat()[7]`? Is it a small number? For example, my boot.py shows 770, because I had not set the clock on the microcontroller when I created it. But if I set the clock first and then upload a new copy of boot.py it shows `os.stat()[7]` in the hundreds of millions of seconds.

Comment: @DaveH. the file is created on a Mac and uploaded using `ampy` so the modified time is properly set. On the Pico I'm getting values like 1609459246 which is close but incorrect. `time.time()` gives eg 1695719529

Answer (score 1):

Before copying files, I used rshell to synchronise the clock on the Pico. The last modification date for the copied files is now correct.

```
rshell date -b pyboard
```